# Call to API in WPF application is not working

Tags: wpf, api

I am new to WPF. I cloned this application from github and now trying to compile it. It is throwing error.

Can someone please help to resolve this?

> The type or namespace name 'SessionAgentApi' could not be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The API `SessionAgentApi` is inside the `Connected Services` in the application.

[image: my api]

When I see the api folder in my file explorer, I can see these are the files sitting inside.
`xx.SessionAgentApi.LaunchMpegStreamerProcessResponse.datasource`
`configuration.svcinfo`
`configuration91.svcinfo`
`Reference.cs`
`Reference.svcmap`
`service1.wsdl`
`service1.xsd`
`service2.xsd`

I am calling this api inside the below class inside the same project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace xx
{
    public partial class UserSessionAgent: IDisposable
    {
        static readonly object lockObject = new object();     
     
        bool tryOpenApi(int timeoutMss = 3000)
        {           
                if (apiClient == null)
                    apiClient = new SessionAgentApi.ApiClient();
                try
                {
                    apiClient.Open();
                   ...
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.Warning2(ex);
                }
                apiClient.Abort();
                apiClient = null;
            }
           
            return false;
        }
        SessionAgentApi.ApiClient apiClient;
    }
}
```

Comment: So where's this class defined - is it not in the project ? Is it in a separate nuget package ? Not really much we can do to help with this - the error pretty much explains the problem...

Comment: @auburg, I am calling the api in one of the class inside the same project where this api resides.

Comment: "this application from github"? What application?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a WCF service and need to generate the proxy classes. Use  [svcutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe). Run it in the same directory as your wsdl file:

```
svcutil /t code service1.wsdl
```